# Refund times payment gateway

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment, payment-processing

I am building a marketplace app and wanted to process the refunds to customers whenever they make a cancellation or their requested service is cancelled.

I know some apps such as Freenow, deliveroo and many others process refunds immediately.

I am using stripe now but was wondering if I am using the wrong payment gateway or if there is something that I am missing as it says in the official website that it takes between 5-10 days to process refunds.

STRIPE DOCS:
`When there is sufficient funds in your Stripe account balance, Stripe submits refunds to your customer's bank immediately. Depending on the bank's processing time, it can take anywhere from 5-10 business days to show up on your customer's bank account.`

My app is still in development but I was wondering whether I should go ahead with stripe or not.

Thanks.

Comment: The delay is not in the app's processing, but how long the bank transfer takes to hit your account. In the US that can take days; in other countries it might be instant. It depends a bit on the bank as well. Stripe is not unusual in this regard, and 5-10 days tends to be the worst-case scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're not talking about reversals, rather than refunds, in this case ?
https://stripe.com/docs/refunds#refund-requests

> Some refunds—those issued shortly after the original charge—appear in the form of a reversal instead of a refund. In the case of a reversal, the original charge drops off the customer’s statement, and a separate credit isn’t issued.

This wouldn't be delayed by the 5-10 days mentioned elsewhere for refunds, as the funds never technically left the customer's bank account since settlement takes a few working days.

These are more of a refresh-rate issue on the bank statement at that point. Reversals apply to any refunds made, through Stripe or any other gateway.

Answer (score -1):

Those "other apps" move tens of millions of dollars monthly, and so payment gateways are willing to negotiate custom contracts with them to bypass the 5 - 10 day bank fraud checks. If you can consistently move the same amount of money through a payment gateway, you might be able to negotiate a similar contract.

And no, this is not specific to Stripe. You aren't going to find any payment gateway willing to take on the risk of an arbitrary user like yourself signing up, then getting their friends to claim instant refunds and thus defraud the gateway.